# how can i use LRTIM and RTRIM to find invalid records and insert it into error table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a query that finds the invalid records from each column in a table. but the length of the data type is not same for all the columns. I am saying this because when I use LTRIM and RTRIM , it gives an error "**The type of column "SubscriberLastName" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list**" and if I CAST that column then no result.

Can anybody help me with that?

```
Insert into ErrorTable (------) select (-----)
From (
            select [SubscriberDataId]
            ,Case When ltrim(rtrim([SubscriberCode])) = '' Then [SubscriberCode] Else 'CorrectValue' end as [SubscriberCode]
            ,Case When ltrim(rtrim([SubscriberLastName]))= '' Then [SubscriberLastName] Else 'CorrectValue' end as [SubscriberLastName]
            ,Case When ltrim(rtrim([SubscriberFirstName]))= ''  Then [SubscriberFirstName] Else 'CorrectValue' end as [SubscriberFirstName]
            from Facets.SubscriberData) [sd]
            Unpivot
            (ErrorValue for FieldName in ([SubscriberCode],
            [SubscriberLastName],[SubscriberFirstName] )) as x
            where x.ErrorValue <> 'CorrectValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the TYPEs are the same, not just the lengths.

```
Insert into ErrorTable (------) select (-----)
From (
            select [SubscriberDataId]
            ,Case When ltrim(rtrim([SubscriberCode])) = '' Then CAST([SubscriberCode] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) Else 'CorrectValue' end as [SubscriberCode]
            ,Case When ltrim(rtrim([SubscriberLastName]))= '' Then CAST([SubscriberLastName] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) Else 'CorrectValue' end as [SubscriberLastName]
            ,Case When ltrim(rtrim([SubscriberFirstName]))= ''  Then CAST([SubscriberFirstName] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) Else 'CorrectValue' end as [SubscriberFirstName]
            from Facets.SubscriberData) [sd]
            Unpivot
            (ErrorValue for FieldName in ([SubscriberCode],
            [SubscriberLastName],[SubscriberFirstName] )) as x
            where x.ErrorValue <> 'CorrectValue'
```

Comment: Hi @Cyberkiwi, thanks for ur reply i already tried that but y i am getting no result. i am getting 3 columns SubscriberDataId, ErrorValue and FieldName and all 3 columns blank.

Comment: What do you get for just this `select [SubscriberDataId]
            ,Case When .... [SubscriberFirstName]
            from Facets.SubscriberData` (the inner select) - add it to the question

Comment: i get, under SubscriberDataId (1,2,3....) and under SubscriberFirstName (CorrectValue,CorrectValue.... )

Comment: @Programmer: Your script seems to select (and insert) *only* blank values. What did you intend it to do actually? I mean, before unpivoting you could see full rows where some columns were blank, but after unpivoting *and* applying the filter you can only get the blanks, because all the `CorrectValues` get filtered out. Wasn't that your actual intention? And one more thing: trailing spaces are ignored in SQL Server when comparing strings, so you don't need `RTRIM`. And, as you are actually comparing to `''`, `LTRIM` is not needed either.